# DateListPlot - ToolTip

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I would like to plot some data in time and am trying to format it so that tooltips on mouse over gives the date and a value.

Something of the form

```
    DateListPlot[Tooltip[data,
    StringForm["Time: ``, ``= ``", DateString[data[[x, 1]],{"Month","/", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute"}],Title, data[[x, 2]]]]]
```

Is similar to what I want except I need data[[x,1]] or data[[x,2]] to have x as a reference to the current position DateListPlot is in the list so that mouse overs give correct time/value.

This example works when I just make x some number 1 <= x <= length(data).

Comment: Look up `MapIndexed`, and pure functions using (# &).

Answer (score 13):

For illustrative purposes:

```
dt = DateRange[{2014, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 31}];
v = RandomInteger[{5, 10}, 31];
dat = Transpose[{dt, v}];
tt = Tooltip[#, 
     Row[{DateString[
        First@#, {"DayNameShort", ", ", "Day", " ", "MonthNameShort", 
         " ", "Year"}], ": ", Style[Last@#, Red, Bold]}], 
     TooltipStyle -> {Background -> White, CellFrameColor -> Blue, 
       CellFrame -> 2}] & /@ dat;
DateListPlot[tt, PlotMarkers -> {Style[©, Red], 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: i like the © Sign, it says see, see, see ...

Comment: Can you apply this to multiple date lists of the form {dat1,dat2}

Comment: @Boris  if the 2  or more dat are prepared as tooltips it should work. You could write a generic function to prepare time series. Good luck :)

Comment: Yes, I tried 2 tt functions, but this is part of a larger project and I do need a generic as you suggest. Sadly this is beyond me - I tried, believe me. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @Boris I would make the tooltip assignment a function then map it to your timeseries the DateListPlot. I

Comment: @Boris I am sorry I don’t have time to go into more detail.